# C# Doesn't recognize empty cell using SQL,oleDB

Tags: c#, sql, database, null, oledb

When i'm trying to get a value from my access table,and the cell is empty, I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

its happening when I'm trying to get information from the triplets columns.it may has'nt any value in the cell, but must has in triplet1's column.
heres part of the code I wrote.

```
public Codons(string name)
{
    this.start = false;
    this.end = false;
    this.dataconnection = new OleDbConnection();
    this.dataconnection.ConnectionString =              "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
    this.dataconnection.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT tblCodons.codonsCodon1, tblCodons.codonsCodon3, "+
    "tblCodons.codonsTriplet1, tblCodons.codonsTriplet2, tblCodons.codonsTriplet3, "+
    "tblCodons.codonsTriplet4, tblCodons.codonsTriplet5, tblCodons.codonsTriplet6, "+
    "tblCodons.codonsFullName, tblCodons.codonsStart, tblCodons.codonsEnd"
    +" FROM tblCodons"
    +" WHERE tblCodons.codonsFullName=?";

    OleDbCommand mycomm = new OleDbCommand(sql, dataconnection);
    mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("codonsFullName", name);
    OleDbDataReader dataReader = mycomm.ExecuteReader();

    dataReader.Read();
    this.codon1 = dataReader.GetString(0);
    this.codon3 = dataReader.GetString(1);
    this.triplet1 = dataReader.GetString(2);
    if (dataReader.GetString(3) == "")
        this.triplet2 = "     ";
    else
    this.triplet2 = dataReader.GetString(3);

    if (dataReader.GetString(4) == "")
        this.triplet3 = "     ";
    else
    this.triplet3 = dataReader.GetString(4);

    if (dataReader.GetString(5) == "")
        this.triplet4 = "     ";
    else
    this.triplet4 = dataReader.GetString(5);

    if (dataReader.GetString(6) == "")
        this.triplet5 = "     ";
    else
    this.triplet5 = dataReader.GetString(6);

    if (dataReader.GetString(7) == "")
        this.triplet6 = "     ";
    else
    this.triplet6 = dataReader.GetString(7);

    this.fullName = dataReader.GetString(8);
    this.start = dataReader.GetBoolean(9);
    this.end = dataReader.GetBoolean(10);
    dataReader.Close();
```

I have also tried null instead of "".

TNX for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Set your string property to `(dataReader[3] as string) ?? "     "`.  When a database field is null, the type is `DBNull` with value `DBNull.Value` rather than being type `string` with value `null`.

You can also check use a conditional like `dataReader[3] == DBNull.Value` before calling `GetString` to check if the field is null.

Comment: Brian thanks for clarifying my typo / mistake I am glad that someone can pickup on what I was trying to say.. thanks and I agree it's always better to check first than assume

Answer (score 0):

in your code example where you are checking for something like this

```
  if (dataReader.GetString(3) == "")
      this.triplet2 = "     ";
```

I would recommend using `== string.empty;` or use the `isNullOrEmpty()` method.
There is a difference between Null & empty

So where you have this `this.triplet2 = dataReader.GetString(3);` 
try to cast as an object something like this

```
this.triplet2 = (dataReader.GetString(3) as object) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

DBNull is also your best option

Comment: This will still cause a casting exception.  The casting error is caused by the call to `GetString` trying to cast a `DBNull` to a `string`.  It is too late to recover by then; it won't even get a chance to cast to `object`.

Comment: awesome perhaps you can click the up arrow to vote this one. glad that we could help